# How to save two different values from one dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

in the backend a user can select a country via dropdown menu, e.g. "Germany". The frontend is bilingual so i have to dump "Germany" if language A is set and "Deutschland" if language B is set.

How can i save the selection and its translation to separate fields in the database?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a array where you save the multilingual query and pick the value you like to use.
or use a  id like

1 for germany,deutschland,etc
2 for usa,america etc
3 for uk,england etc

```
<--- name="contry" value="1"> Germany </>
```

or

```
<--- name="contry" value="1"> Deutsch </>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a lookup value for the Name for each language. Once the selected value is retrieved, you can make a lookup. Otherwise, in the codebehind, get the SelectedItem and SelectedValue to get both of them.

Comment: With "lookup value" you mean 1 = Germany/Deutschland, 2 = France/Frankreich ...
That results in a lot of if statements in the frontend, doesn't it? Like: if lang=en and value=1 echo Germany ...
I'm worried about the performance.
Could you shortly explain how to get both the SelectedItem and the value? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I did it as follows:

BACKEND:

```
<select name="country">
<option value="Deutschland:Germany">Deutschland</option>
<option value="Frankreich:France">Frankreich</option>
...
</select>
```

FRONTEND:

```
$countries = explode(':', $country);
$country_de = $countries[0];
$country_en = $countries[1];
```